# Finding roots of equation in table form

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I would like to find roots of legendre polynomial
`NRoots[LegendreP[4, x]== 0, x]` , 
I'm  getting
`x == -0.861136 || x == -0.339981 || x == 0.339981 || x == 0.861136` as output.

Instead i need my output as `{  -0.861136 , -0.339981 , 0.339981 ,0.861136}`

Could you please suggest me what type of modification i should make in input code 
so that i get my output as `{  -0.861136 , -0.339981 , 0.339981 ,0.861136}`

Comment: Use `NSolve[]` instead: `x /. NSolve[LegendreP[4, x] == 0, x]`.

Comment: @J.M. Aside from the format, I would assume that `NRoots` and `NSolve` use different algorithms, so, conceivably, the OP would like to use the former for algorithmic reasons?!

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer `NRoots` to `NSolve` as suggested by J.M., you can do

```
x /. Rule @@ # & /@ (List @@ NRoots[LegendreP[4, x] == 0, x]
```

Comment: I'd use `ToRules[]` myself if the OP insists on using `NRoots[]`: `x /. {ToRules[NRoots[LegendreP[4, x] == 0, x]]}`.

Answer (score 2):

For your specified problem you can [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for exact solutions

```
roots = Simplify[x /. Solve[LegendreP[4, x] == 0, x]]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
LegendreP[4, #] & /@ roots

(*  {0, 0, 0, 0}  *)
```

Then, if desired, use [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) with any desired precision

```
roots // N[#, 20] &

(*  {-0.33998104358485626480, 0.33998104358485626480, 
     -0.86113631159405257522, 0.86113631159405257522}  *)
```